# Are bijective polynomials of degree $2 \bmod 2^m$ efficiently inverted?

Tags: hash, modular-arithmetic, one-way-function, bijection

Take a bijective polynomial of degree $2 \bmod 2^{64}$ like:

$m = (n(n+1)/2)\ \bmod 2^{64}$

It is bijective and can trivially be inverted for numbers up to $2^{32}$ by calculating $\lfloor\sqrt{2m}\rfloor$ . For all other numbers the inversion is not that trivial but I have the feeling it could be done without brute force.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Is this homework?

Comment: @kelalaka No, cryptography is a hobby, hashing [part of my research](https://1ykos.github.io/patchmap/), but I'm missing essential mathematical education, I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I legitimately do not know if it is efficiently inverted, if not it could be a novel one-way function.

Comment: It can be efficiently inverted - does that answer your question?

Comment: @poncho How do you know it can be efficiently inverted?

Comment: Because I figured out how to invert it. It's not that hard, you can figure it out as well (it's a technique that comes in useful time to time). Hint: the lower  $i$ bits of  $m$ depend solely on the lower $i+1$ bits of $n$ ; any other bits of  $n$
have no effect...

Comment: @poncho This works, great! O(log(n)), do you want to write an answer, if not, I'll do it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by poncho `m` only depends on the lower `i+1` bits of `n` . Therefore `n` can be reconstructed by testing the four possible states of the the two most significant bits at a time, starting with the first ones, then choosing the combination that produces the correct binary suffix to expand iteratively.